# What species are the Ones?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-clone-wars

In Star Wars there is a group of powerful beings known as "The Ones". Is there more of this species that are talked about somewhere? I know that Abeloth used artificial means to make her into a creature similar to "The Ones" but was not sure if there is any more natural born ones.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield not sure, but you may want to be more specific. "Force Wielder" is interpreted in Star Wars to mean "someone who can wield the Force". That's basically any trained Force-sensitive, independent of species, gender etc. So your question kinda doesn't make sense. You probably need to reword the terminology used.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Actually, there's a species called Force Wielders. Limited info available but check my answer.

Comment: @JohnBell well, if there is then they are little known. I didn't know The Father/Son/Daughter is of a named species myself. I believe my reasoning likely still stands as to why there are downvotes.

Comment: @thegreatjedi It's clear in the question he's talking about a particular group of characters, and a google search can tell you quickly that they're specifically referred to as "Force Wielders", note the capitalization of the words. I don't agree with down voting without researching it first.

Comment: @JohnBell I didn't downvote him, I'm just suggesting the likely reason for why other people downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The only information I can find is based on Wikia, and I am reluctant to link that site, as it's been proved incorrect so many times. However, it seems the only source on the web is [this](http://clonewars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Wielder) article.

The key thing to take from this is the opening paragraph:

> *"The Force Wielders were a force sensitive family who resided on
>   Mortis. There were three of them who each stood for one part of the
>   Force in The Galaxy."*

It seems they were spiritual beings evolved from the "Celestials", who represented three aspects of the force, the light side (Daughter), the dark side (Son) and neutral (Father). Some species worshiped them as gods, as a trinity. That's the only information available.